# IOS: In-app purchases work on TestFlight but dont work on release

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store, testflight

In-app purchases don't work in app's release version (from AppStore).

In TestFlight I can purchase the items. But in Appstore version I cannot (nothing happens).

I wonder how my app has passed the AppleReviewTeam and Ready for Sale...

When I tap "buy-button" purchase should happen and it is working on TestFlight. But in Appstore-version of the app it is do not working. Also it can 'parse' (and show in app) price of the in-app purchases.

The problem was occured when I started using new Xcode 11.4.

1. I upload the app in TestFlight via Xcode11.4.
2. In-app purchase work properly in TestFlight tests.
3. I send to review and the app succesfully "Ready for sale".
4. I download the app from Appstore.
5. In-app purchase dont work (when I try to buy there is nothing happens). Internet connection is ok.

May it be the problem with provisioning profiles or what?

It passed about several weeks, Apple support can't help me (not via phone not via email).

Maybe community can hep me? Please.

Comment: Why can Apple Support not help? surely they would be the best option, although they can be quite slow to respond

Comment: I dont know why.. Last they said: "make a code-level support request". I am waiting for now.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @geohei Actually not, I have downgraded inapp-purchases-plugin to old version. They didn't help me with code-level-support (said it is a code mistake). In addition I noticed that for now there are moments (about day or about) when inapp-purchases dont work, but then it works again. Something wrong with Apple mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Each in-app purchase should be cleared for sale for a review at the time of deploying in **Features** section of the app in appstoreconnect (**Appstore Connect->YOUR_APP->Features->In App Purchase->YOUR_IN_APP_PURCHASE->clear for sale**).

Also when you upload the app for the first time, you should send the in app purchase also for review along with the app. If you didn't add in app purchase at that time, the app will only be reviewed, not in app purchase.

Check if your in app purchase is in **approved** state in features section.

Comment: Yes, the purchases Approved and Clear for Sale. I have made an update of my app via new Xcode11. Before, the purchases work perfectly (via older Xcode10).